# Tell Angular ng-app to ignore specific internal Dom

Tags: angularjs

We have a pretty massive app and currently want angular to ignore specific internal DOM areas due to performance. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by [ng-non-bindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angNonBindable).